# Unexpected mix of '||' and '&&' no-mixed-operators

Tags: reactjs, pusher-js

I have the following hook and we use it to bind to channels.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Channel, PresenceChannel } from "pusher-js";
import PrivateChannel from 'pusher-js/types/src/core/channels/private_channel';
import { usePusher } from "./usePusher";

export type ChannelType = PrivateChannel | PresenceChannel

function _useChannel<T extends ChannelType>(channelName: string) {
    const pusher = usePusher()
    const [channel, setChannel] = useState<T>();

    useEffect(() => {
        const pusherChannel = pusher.subscribe(channelName) as T;
        setChannel(pusherChannel);

        return () => pusher?.unsubscribe(channelName);
    }, [channelName, pusher]);

    return channel;
}
```

When I open the console, I see this message: `Unexpected mix of '||' and '&&'  no-mixed-operators`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Well, somewhere you have code that does something like "cond1 || cond2 && cond3" where it needs to instead do "(cond1 || cond2) && cond3" or "cond1 || (cond2 && cond3)". Where is the lint warning/error pointing to in your code?

Comment: There are no conditions. The warning appears in IDE's console and the browser.

Comment: Let me quickly check something.

Comment: I've just deleted IDE's cache, not sure what was going on. All good now.

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible then. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Drew Reese said, you have somewhere a complex logic expression mixing `&&` and `||`, and you have configured ESLint to warn you if that happens. You will have to find where that's happening, and add the necessary parenthesis to clarify your intention.

From [ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-operators)

```
var foo = a && b || c || d;    /*BAD: Unexpected mix of '&&' and '||'.*/
var foo = a && b ? c : d;      /*BAD: Unexpected mix of '&&' and '?:'.*/
var foo = (a && b) ? c : d;    /*GOOD*/
var foo = (a && b) || c || d;  /*GOOD*/
var foo = a && (b || c || d);  /*GOOD*/
```

If you are uncertain about what the correct precedence of boolean operators should be, think that `&&` can be thought as the equivalent of `multiplication` and `||` as `addition`, thus `&&` takes precedence over `||`

For example:

```
a && b || c || d 
<=> a*b + c + d 
<=> (a && b) || c || d
```